# How to implement onKeyDown method as onTouch or onClick?

Tags: android

how i implement onKeyDown method as onTouch or onClick in android . The current method is for hardware keys but i want to change it to onTouch so how can i do that..

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent evt) {
    boolean moved = false;
    switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            moved = maze.move(Maze.UP);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            moved = maze.move(Maze.DOWN);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            moved = maze.move(Maze.RIGHT);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            moved = maze.move(Maze.LEFT);
            break;
        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,evt);
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement OnTouchListener's onTouch method for views like Button..

```
    mButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

               switch ( event.getAction() ) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: break;

                }

                return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: but there is no MotionEvent for Right and left ... what i do now

Comment: In my current method there is action for right and left hardware keys so when these action perform out object move to right or left as pressed but in other hand, in onTouch there is no ActionEvent for these two directions ...

Comment: Can you be more clear on "right and left hardware keys". Are you referring to the keys on Soft keyboard?? If yes, then you have to override onKeyDown method.